Finding a picture edge
I have a picture, that consists of coordinates (x, y) and some intensity parameter in each pixel. It has an irregular shape. Also it can have some holes in it. Here is an example of matrix that i have:
set.seed(20)
test <- expand.grid(1:25, 1:50)
test$Int <- rnorm(nrow(test), 7, 1)
edge_rows <- which(test$Var1 %in% c(1, 25) | test$Var2 %in% c(1, 50))
rows_to_remove <- sample(edge_rows, 50) 
test <- test[-rows_to_remove, ]
edge_rows <- which(test$Var1 %in% c(2, 24) | test$Var2 %in% c(2, 49))
rows_to_remove <- sample(edge_rows, 25) 
test <- test[-rows_to_remove, ]
rows_to_remove <- sample(edge_rows, 75) 
test <- test[-sample(nrow(test), 50), ]
ggplot(test) +
    geom_tile(aes(Var1, Var2, fill = Int))

Pixels that don't have an (x, y, Int) annotation and surrounded with other pixels are considered to be holes, and i'm looking for indexes of just for edges.
Thank you in advance

I'm a little unclear about your 'resulting index of edges' but will attempt/suggest:
library(terra)
test_rast = terra::rast(test) # your data as above

plot(boundaries(test_rast, classes = FALSE, inner = TRUE)) # or
# test_bound_inner <- boundaries(test_rast, classes = FALSE, inner = TRUE)
# plot is wrapping the boundaries function but doesn't result in an object, just the plot
# plot(test_bound_inner) 
# retains test_bound_inner as an object in your session


or:
plot(boundaries(test_rast, classes = FALSE, inner = FALSE))
# test_bound_inF <- boundaries(test_rast, classes = FALSE, inner = FALSE)


A couple of thoughts on x/y indexing - here using your less preferred second image above.
test_bound_inF_mtx <- as.matrix(test_bound_inF, wide = TRUE)
> which(test_bound_inF_mtx == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
        row col
   [1,]   1   1
   [2,]   3   1
   [3,]   5   1
   [4,]  10   1
   [5,]  12   1
   [6,]  13   1
   [7,]  14   1
   [8,]  15   1
   [9,]  16   1
  [10,]  17   1
<---snip--->

But, if the overall trajectory to further align successive slices, (say if building 3D elaborations) you'll likely want some variant of ?terra::?xyFromCell which gives x/y of centroid of pixel. Slices can be 'stacked' simply with my_many_slices <- c(slice1, slice1, slice3 & etc).

wow, it indeed draws boundaries, but i cann't understand, how can i find that (x,y) meanings of obtained pixels, or row indexes from the initial table that form boundaries

So, above, we have step 1. Which plot more closely reflects your thinking/intuition?

definitely first one

I would have guessed the second, as first seems to put more emphasis on 'holes', due to the choice of default 'queen', i.e. 8 surrounding pixel values (in boundary) but looks 'better-ish', and two will return a sparser 'segments' as viewed upon '0'. Ultimately, what are you looking for?, i.e. why is the 'ragged edge' next useful? And look at `boundaries( directions = 4) instead of 8.

In my real issue this picture is a tissue slice, und it should have closed boundaries. Seems like first picture is closer to this situation. And also i want coordinates of obtained boundaries were included in the set of coordinates of the original table. Seems like in the second pictures it doesn't work like that.

And as tissue slice, the slices need to 'align', if stacked like pancakes? But, perhaps you're after something more like image processing after raster edge detection?

no, slices need not to be stacked. I need just their coordinates/indexes. Seems like your last answer update solves the problem, but how did we get "test_bound_inF"?

Updated above, with object creation rather than just making plot. Still think you'll want to explore EBImage package as it has segmentation algos specific to microscopy and that is your data. And as mentioned, xyFromCell will likely provide easier index than my which arr,ind above.
